# SAP Smartform totals misalignment

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I'm using a template to try to nicely align all of the "totals" of the document.

[image]

- A style has been created and is set to "right"
- The information is text elements combined with variables
- The variables have been checked to make sure there are no spaces

In the print preview from SAP it seems to be going OK.

However, when I print it out on paper it's adding it's own padding or margin.

[image]

I'm not sure where this is coming from or why it's being formatted this way. I've also tried taking the text and placing it in a type STRING but that produces the same result.

What code I've tried:

**Attempt #1) Text Includes**

- Subtotal
- &DISCOUNT_TEXT&
- Total &CURRENCY& Excl. Tax
- &TAXPERCENT&% Tax
- Total &CURRENCY& Incl. Tax

&DISCOUNT_TEXT& = String

&CURRENCY& = WAERK

&TAXPERCENT& = Integer

**Attempt #2) String literals**

```
test_text-subtotal = 'Subtotal'.
test_text-discount = &discount_text&.
test_text-excltax = `Total ` && currency && ` Excl. Tax`.
test_text-taxpercent = taxpercent && `% Tax`.
test_text-incltax = `Total ` && currency && ` Incl. Tax`.
```

Comment: Please add the images to the question as inline images - and please also add the code (text including symbols) that is used to actually produce the output.

Comment: I have to have at least 10 reputation to include images, and I wanted to link more images but I also have to have 10 reputation to include more than 2. In either case, I'll edit the post to include what I've tried.

Comment: Just to let you know, I can't reproduce the issue here. Are you using a custom printer driver / device type?

Comment: No, I get the same result when printing it to a PDF. even weirder then typing it in without any variables it produces a similar effect but different positions. I'm going to attempt to just recreate the entire template.

Comment: @vwegert which font did you use to attempt to reproduce it? Recreating the template didn't work and only produced the same misalignment. It's a customer delivered font, so I'm assuming it probably has to do with that.

Comment: Probably it's impossible to align those lines ideally as variable can adopt any value

Answer (score 0):

It is usually because of your printer settings. I faced this issue before. You got no choice other than setting your alignments based on the printer output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Word as editor? if so, switch to the old sapscript editor and check the paragraph styles again. I think I see that the TAXPERCENT line is not in bold, so it could be a different style.